# Change value in onlick web page option using vba (IE 11)

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, dom

I'am new in VBA DOM oblject and i'm trying to select a specific option in a web page. Unfortunatly that option has an ID name that is the same as others option in the page except for the value of the inner function.
here the web code:

```
<table class="stati_check" id="ctl00_NetSiuCPH_ctl25">
<tr>
<td>
<span class="check">
<INPUT onclick="if (!boxWorkflow_rbSelect(this)) return;setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$NetSiuCPH$ctl25$ctl00$WorkflowState\',\'\')', 0)" tabIndex=0 
id=ctl00_NetSiuCPH_ctl25_ctl00_WorkflowState type=radio 
value=ONVALIDAPROOF name=ctl00$NetSiuCPH$ctl25$ctl00$WorkflowState>
</span>
<td>
<span class="check">
<INPUT onclick="if (!boxWorkflow_rbSelect(this)) return;setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$NetSiuCPH$ctl25$ctl01$WorkflowState\',\'\')', 0)" tabIndex=0 
id=ctl00_NetSiuCPH_ctl25_ctl01_WorkflowState type=radio 
value=ONANNULA1 name=ctl00$NetSiuCPH$ctl25$ctl01$WorkflowState>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As can be see the two ID are the same so when I run the VBA code line:

```
Set pdr_button = ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_NetSiuCPH_ctl25_ctl00_WorkflowState").click
```

It will be selected only the first option, but i'm trying to select the ones with the value "ONANNULA1".
I've tried with remove/setatribute:

```
Set Annulla_Button = ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_NetSiuCPH_ctl25_ctl00_WorkflowState")
Annulla_Button.removeAttribute ("value")
Annulla_Button.setAttribute ("value"), "ONANNULLA1"
Annulla_Button.Click
```

However the result is that nothing will be selected.

Can someone help me. 
thanks in advance for you patience

Comment: did you try : Set Annulla_Button = ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_NetSiuCPH_ctl25_ctl00_WorkflowState")(1)

Comment: @h2so4 - getElementById doesn't return a collection of elements, it returns a single element.

Comment: Try selecting the table first, then return all the input tags in the table and check the value. E.g. `set elements = ie.document.getelementByID("ctl00_NetSiuCPH_ctl25").getElementsByTagName("input")` then iterate the elements collection to find when the value is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that the strip of code:`

```
Set TABELLA_STATI = ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_NetSiuCPH_ctl25").getElementsByTagName("TR")
For Each tr In TABELLA_STATI
 Set coltd = tr.getElementsByTagName("TD")
For Each td In coltd
Set option_Button = td.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
Option_Value = option_Button(0).Value
If InStr(1, Option_Value, "ONANNUL") > 0 Then
option_Button(0).Click
Exit For
End If
Next td
Next tr
```

`